# shouldChangeCharactersInRange : not working properly

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uitextfield

I am trying to check every character entered into the text field and then trying to print something based on the last character entered.
This is my code:

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string   
{
        if ([textField.text hasSuffix:@"1"]) {
            NSLog(@"Number : %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"NOT ONE : %@",textField.text);
        }
return YES;
}
```

So that means, only when 1 is typed, "NUMBER : 1" must be printed in log, otherwise "NOT ONE : a" or something must be printed.

But I get the following output :

> INPUT is : 123456123

```
2012-12-21 17:41:14.365 vmsipPhone[1866:c07] NOT ONE : 
2012-12-21 17:41:16.125 vmsipPhone[1866:c07] Number : 1
2012-12-21 17:41:17.549 vmsipPhone[1866:c07] NOT ONE : 12
2012-12-21 17:41:19.037 vmsipPhone[1866:c07] NOT ONE : 123
2012-12-21 17:41:20.100 vmsipPhone[1866:c07] NOT ONE : 1234
2012-12-21 17:41:21.694 vmsipPhone[1866:c07] NOT ONE : 12345
2012-12-21 17:41:24.844 vmsipPhone[1866:c07] NOT ONE : 123456
2012-12-21 17:41:25.725 vmsipPhone[1866:c07] Number : 1234561
2012-12-21 17:41:26.836 vmsipPhone[1866:c07] NOT ONE : 12345612
```

The problem is, the first NOT ONE, appears when I type 1
Then when I type 2 : Number : 1 appears
its like a lag of one character.

Could someone explain why is it so. And is there anything wrong that I am doing?

Comment: Just change this line if ([string isEqualToString:@"1"]) Hope it helps you

Comment: @prateek but after removing this line how it checks 1 next time.

Comment: @Girish : Previously itself you understand that 1 has occurred, so it makes no sense in checking that again and again..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is being called **before** the content of `textField.text` is changed.  When you return `YES` from the method, the changes are then applied.  You should create a temporary string, modify it using the range and replacement string and then test that.

Eg:

```
NSMutableString *testString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];
[testString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
if ([testString hasSuffix:@"1"]) {
  // ...
```

Comment: Excellent answer, the explanation and the solution are both perfect. Thanks you.